# How to remove dependencies that I installed manually

Tags: 14.04, server, apt, 64-bit

I was trying to install wkhtmlpdf and after I googled for instructions I found out that I needed to install some dependencies like

```
apt-get install openssl build-essential xorg libssl-dev
```

then I found out that I need to open some kind of x11 server or whatever, and it got to complicated so I gave up and removed wkhtmltopdf.

But how can I remove all that other stuff too?
I think I need openssl but I dont think I need xorg, and I dont know whats build-essential :/

Basically I want to remove everything that was required by wkhtmltopdf, but isn't required by any other app that is currently installed

Answer (score 0):

Running the following command will do:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

From the man page: ***autoremove*** is used to remove packages that were automatically installed to satisfy dependencies for other packages and are now no longer needed.

Additionally, You can also run the following to remove any partially downloaded or broken package:

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

**EDIT:**

After reading your question again i think as you have installed the packages manually you have to remove them manually. The **autoremove** command will then remove any dependencies left (that are not being used by any other package) by your manually removed packages. So to remove the packages you need to run:

```
sudo apt-get remove <package>
```

or if you want to remove the configuration files too:

```
sudo apt-get purge <package>
```

After that you can run **autoremove** to clean up the orphan dependencies.

**EDIT_2:**

I think i have found found an easier solution. You have used the following command to install dependencies manually:

```
apt-get install openssl build-essential xorg libssl-dev
```

Now you want to keep just **openssl** removing the rest three at once. To do so you need to mark the rest three packages as **auto** i.e. automatically installed (as dependencies):

```
sudo apt-mark auto build-essential xorg libssl-dev
```

Now as these packages are marked as auto you can remove them (if they are not real dependencies) by running `sudo apt-get autoremove`.

Now what if you made a mistake and you don't want **xorg** to be marked as **auto** i.e. automatically installed, to do so you need to set **xorg** as manually installed:

```
sudo apt-mark manual xorg
```